# UWP vertical separator with gradient

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I try to use LinearGradientBrush in my xaml code to draw a **1px** vertical separator with gradient at the top. But in my sample I get different results depending of the width of my line. I don't understand why... 
Could someone help me ?

**Final result**

[image]

**Here is my sample code.** 
For each line it is the same gradient definition. Only the width changed. 5px  line seems OK, the two other looks wrong.

```
<Grid>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
    <!-- first separator -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    <!-- second -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    <!-- tird-->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="White"/>

  <Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
      <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
          <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.25"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#FF0000" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF0000"/>
  </Grid>

  <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="White"/>

  <Grid Grid.Column="3">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
      <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
          <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.25"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#FF0000" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF0000"/>
  </Grid>

  <Grid Grid.Column="4" Background="White"/>

  <Grid Grid.Column="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
      <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
          <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.25"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#FF0000" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF0000"/>
  </Grid>

  <Grid Grid.Column="6" Background="White"/>


</Grid>
```

Maybe there is an other way to do that?

Comment: I can reproduce this issue on the 1 px color and when the first `GradientStop` 's offset >=0.5, the color will be the start color, otherwise it will be the end color.